# Is SSHD works with multiple OS?

Tags: 16.04, windows, hard-drive, hardware

I have 1 TB SSHD on my laptop and I installed both ubuntu 16.04 and windows 10 on it by partitioning below.

[image]

My laptop is toshiba and this is the disk It has.
https://eshop.macsales.com/item/Toshiba/MQ02ABD100H/

Is both OS capable of use SSHD functions? or just one of them? or any of them?

Comment: I've removed the `sshd` tag - in the context of this forum, it refers to the Secure Shell Daemon software (unrelated to "Solid State Hybrid Drive")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as sshd's are concerned, the flash essentially is transparent to the 'end user'. In most cases it would be transparent to the underlying os too, but this may vary- some modes let the OS determine some of the use of the flash.

Essentially the flash acts as a secondary layer of cache, rather than a seperate device and both OSes should be able to use it.

Comment: how can I be sure that?

Comment: Its how modern SSHDs work. If its transparent, there ought to be no way to check ;p

Answer (score 0):

Both OS should be capable of using the SSHD function, as the built-in SSHD Processor determines which files should be stored on the SSD Cache.